# How can I specify callback arguments in ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I specify a function that will execute after either an error or success in my $http call?

Here's the code that I have:

```
 topicsRetrieve = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
        var self = this;
        var defer = self.$q.defer();
        var url = "/api/Topic/Retrieve/" +
            self.sus.subject.id;
        self.topicHttp = true;
        self.$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: self.ac.dataServer + url
        })
            .then(
                (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<ITopic[]>): any => {
                    self.topics = angular.copy(response.data);
                    self.topicsBase = angular.copy(response.data);
                    return this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                        subjectId: self.sus.subject.id
                    });
                },
                (error): any => {
                    self.topics = null;
                    self.topicsBase = null;
                    defer.reject(error);
                }
                )
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

What I want is to be able to set `self.topicHttp = false` AFTER the $http call has completed, even if the $http call fails.

Also can someone please verify this is the correct way for me to be returning a promise for this function. I added the code, it seems to work but I'd like to be sure I am doing it the correct way.

Comment: You can add another .then function to run your final code block even if the case is succeeded or errored. See my answer with working demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707589/how-can-i-specify-callback-arguments-in-ng-ihttppromisecallbackarg/32711707#32711707)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/t3kcwc7y/90/)**

You can use second `then()` function to run final code after the success or error case. I have used javascript in the demo, you can try it but you can have a look at following code for your version.

```
topicsRetrieve = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
        var self = this;
        var defer = self.$q.defer();
        var url = "/api/Topic/Retrieve/" +
            self.sus.subject.id;
        self.topicHttp = true;
        self.$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: self.ac.dataServer + url
        })
            .then(
                (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<ITopic[]>): any => {
                    self.topics = angular.copy(response.data);
                    self.topicsBase = angular.copy(response.data);
                    return this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                        subjectId: self.sus.subject.id
                    });
                },
                (error): any => {
                    self.topics = null;
                    self.topicsBase = null;
                    defer.reject(error);
                }
                )
            .then(
                (value): any => {
                    self.topicHttp = false
                }
                )
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

Comment: I was also thinking about a .finally after the first then? Would that also work?

Comment: Yes, you can use .finally() also. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/t3kcwc7y/91/) for demo